# Classic ASP application upgraded form a 2003 server to a new 2008 server issue

Tags: sql-server-2008, asp-classic

I have a working SQL 2008r2 server working with a classic ASP application running on a 2003 server operating system. I upgraded the classic ASP application to a new 2008 server. Only the application IIS settings were copied and the application's ini file updated to reflect the new SQL server's named IP address. Now, the classic ASP application renders in the browser fine but no data for the database is being pulled. The current configuration I have is IIS on the new 2008 server set to anonymous security access and the application pool set to the default classic 2.0 application pool. Also, in the application's ini file the only things changed what the sql server's named ip address. Any ideas?

Comment: I think this is more of a SQL Server question than a Classic ASP one, so I added a SQL Server tag

Answer (score 0):

You probably need to change your connection string within the code, and install a driver that classic ASP can use (the one it is most likely using is not in 64-bit Windows)

• Install sqlncli.msi (http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkID=188401&clcid=0x409)

• Modify your code to use built-in OLEDB driver.

szOpenString = "Provider=SQLNCLI10;Server=" & ServerName & ";Database=" & SQLDatabase & ";Uid=" & UserID & ";Pwd=" & Password & ";Persist Security Info=True"

Comment: Is what you are saying is that the Active Server Pages application running on a server 2003 is using the ODBC drivers data connect type and not ADO? The current configuration I have is IIS on the new 2008 server set to anonymous security access and the application pool set to the default classic 2.0 application pool. Also, in the application's ini file the only things changed what the sql server's named ip address. I think I am missing something but not sure what.

Comment: We had issues in our conversion until we switched to the driver I mentioned above.  It also requires the connection string to change slightly so I provided an example in the answer.